# Error while creating uses-permission from a package

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I am trying to create an android application that bluetooth connects to a third party device and saves the data collected into a database. The problem I am currently having is adding the uses-permission for broadcasting and reading the data from a package. my code is as follows in android manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.daotec.bgextract">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.b3inc.sbir.mdrs.permission.READ_DATA”/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.b3inc.sbir.mdrs.permission.BROADCAST"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

after i placed in the READ DATA permission i got errors all throughout my xml file and the broadcast permission has an error Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix. When i run the application i am getting error The value of attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "uses-permission" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother : https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Answer (score 1):

I think you have copied this line `<uses-permission android:name="com.b3inc.sbir.mdrs.permission.READ_DATA”/>`, Try to replace the double quotes `"`

Answer (score 0):

After `...permission.READ_DATA`, you have a formatted quote - `”`. Replace it with the appropriate quote - `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try out below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.daotec.bgextract">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.b3inc.sbir.mdrs.permission.READ_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.b3inc.sbir.mdrs.permission.BROADCAST" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Replace below line then your issue solved.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.b3inc.sbir.mdrs.permission.READ_DATA" />
```

Issue is **Replace ” with "**